# Why can't we just use its iterator or a for-each loop to visit the values in a java Map(HashMap or TreeMap) in order?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap

I am a beginner in Java. Please explain it as plain as possible. 
I am putting a dummy code, because this site didn't let me post the question without this:

```
public void printSorted(PrintStream out) {
        TreeMap<Integer,String> map2 = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : concord.entrySet()){
            map2.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }//NavigableMap nmap=treemap.descendingMap();
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry2 : map2.descendingMap().entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry2.getValue()+ " " + entry2.getKey());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please add more details about the problem. What are you trying to achieve, what are you expecting to see with the above code (sample though it may be), and what do you actually see?

Comment: ...and a `HashMap`, by definition, doesn't have any order.

Comment: @AndyTurner Unless it's a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the code. What is concord? Please answer z0r's questions, because I can't understand what your question/problem is.

Comment: @cppbeginner ah yes.

Comment: The simplest way to iterate over the values in sorted order is map.values().stream().sorted().forEach(v -> ...);

Comment: Are you asking why one has to iterate over the result of `map.entrySet()` rather than `map` itself?

Comment: My question is , why do we use Map iterator and not use for/each loop?

Comment: But both of your examples show use of a for-each loop.

Comment: The two loops you posted **are** foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we just use its iterator or a for-each loop to visit the values in a java Map(HashMap or TreeMap) in order?

Because those two classes do not maintain the *values* in any order.  (Apart from the implied order of the *keys* ... in the `TreeMap` case.)

Indeed, there is not even a requirement on the value type of a `Map` that it be orderable.

If you want / need the values of a map in order:

- If the ordering you want is "entry insertion order" or "entry least recently used", then use a `LinkedHashMap`.
- For other orderings, you can copy the list of values (or the set of entries) into a separate set and then sort it.  (Or you can do the equivalent with streams without an *explicit* copy.)  But the point is that the `Map` itself won't / can't *maintain* the ordering you have just created by sorting.
- If you want to avoid the cost of repeated sorting, use a separate (incrementally updatable) data structure to keep a sorted list or set of the values.

---

P.S.  If you *actually* are asking about iterating the *keys* or *entries* in order, then `TreeMap` already does that.  And ...

> why do we use Map iterator and not use for/each loop?

We *can* do either.  Both work.  And indeed, a for each loop uses the Iterator under the covers.

You only *need* to use an iterator explicitly if you want to explicitly call methods on the iterator; e.g. `Iterator::remove()`

Comment: Iterating a `TreeMap` *will* iterate the values "in order", i.e. in the order of the keys, either *natural* or defined by `Comparator`.

Comment: @Andreas - I know.  But that's NOT what this question is about.  This is about iterating the **values** ... not the keys.

Comment: So, `for (X x : map.values())` will iterate the **values**, in the order defined by the map. Nothing in the question says OP want to iterate the values in *sorted* order by value. The followup question in a comment *("why do we use Map iterator and not use for/each loop?")* is even further away from that, since OP seems to only care about *method* of iteration, not what the order is.